# Permission denied when running program from make

Tags: permissions, make

I'm trying to debug a problem, where I can not run `flutter` from make.

This is my minimum `Makefile` which reproduces the issue.

```
fails:
    flutter doctor

works:
    sh -c flutter doctor
```

And the corresponding output:

```bsh
➜ make fails
flutter --version
make: flutter: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:2: fails] Error 127
```

```bsh
➜ make works
sh -c "flutter --version"
Flutter 2.2.2 • channel stable •
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d79295af24 (7 days ago) • 2021-06-11 08:56:01
-0700
Engine • revision 91c9fc8fe0
Tools • Dart 2.13.3
```

I also observed, that running other executables in my path - like `python`, `go` or whatever works just fine.

I'm wondering how to debug this kind of problem, i.e. how do I find out why exactly the permission was denied and how to fix that.

**EDIT:**
Interestingly if I run `which flutter` and use the full path in the `Makefile`, everything works fine:

```
also-works: 
    which flutter
    /full/path/to/bin/flutter --version
```

with the output:

```bsh
➜ make also-works
which flutter
/full/path/to/bin/flutter
/full/path/to/bin/flutter --version
Flutter 2.2.2 • channel stable •
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d79295af24 (7 days ago) • 2021-06-11 08:56:01
-0700
Engine • revision 91c9fc8fe0
Tools • Dart 2.13.3
```

Comment: Guess: The path set on invocation of `make` is different from the path you get when executing `sh` (through the profiles etc.). To debug, you can `echo` the path (and other environment settings, which might be different).

Comment: I was facing the same issue. For me this was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71448029/356528